# Does Genji get ult from healing?

Tags: overwatch

Healers usually build up ult from healing their allies. But what about Genji? I can think of three instances where he could heal himself/someone else using his Deflect ability:

- Ana's shots
- Ana's Biotic Grenade
- Moira's healing Biotic Orb

(I think he also used to be able to deflect Soldier's Biotic Field, but I'm not sure.)

Does he get any ult charge if he heals this way? And if yes, if his healing target is under the influence of a friendly Ana's Biotic Grenade, does he get more ult charge from healing more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, even if Genji can heal by deflecting heling projectiles, he doesn't gain ultimate charge from it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

All heroes gain ult over time and from doing damage.

However, they also get additional ult from actions that are specifically flagged as doing so, usually from using their abilities.

As a general rule, only healers gain ult charge from healing players.

In fact, one change they made in [Patch 1.20.0.3](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/game/patch-notes/pc#patch-44022) was to make Sombra no longer gain ult when others use her hacked health packs.

Comment: Soldier still gains ult when healing others through his Biotic Field. I think the "general rule" line should be removed, the "using their abilities" line says it all.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna The reason healing is mentioned is because the original question was specifically asking about healing.  Not only that, but not all abilities give you ult charge so it'd still be a general rule and not an absolute one.

Comment: Saying that only healers get ult charge from healing is blatantly false though. Soldier gets some charge from Biotic Field, and Roadhog gets ult from his `estus`, i mean Take a Breather.